# Como ajustar uma data minima no datapicker?

Tags: android, datapicker

Gostaria de colocar uma data minima no meu datapicker, pois não conseguir ainda:
segue abaixo o código para vocÊs poderem me ajudar, sendo que no meu layout so tem um edit text e o datapicker so aparece quando e clico na caixa de texto.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"    tools:context="br.com.eduspaceandroid.cursoandroid.eduspace.Activity.AgendamentoActivity"
    android:id="@+id/dpDatainicial">
    <include android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar"/>
 <EditText
        android:layout_width="130dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:inputType="date"
        android:ems="10"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/etDataInicial"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:hint="@string/hint_Data"
        " />
```

código da minha activity agendamento:

```
public class AgendamentoActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Toolbar toolbarAgendamento;
    private EditText datainicial;
    private int ano;
    private int mes;
    private int dia;
    static final int DATE_DIALOG_ID =0;
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_agendamento);
        toolbarAgendamento=(Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        toolbarAgendamento.setTitle("Agendamento");
        setSupportActionBar(toolbarAgendamento);

        datainicial=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.etDatainicial);
        String data = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").format(new Date());
        datainicial.setText(data);

        datainicial.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID);
            }
        });

    }


    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        switch (id){
            case DATE_DIALOG_ID:

                return new DatePickerDialog(AgendamentoActivity.this,mDateSetListener,
                        dia,mes,ano);

        }
        return null;
    }


    private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener mDateSetListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view,int day, int month, int year ) {

            dia = day;
            mes = month;
            ano = year;

            updateDisplay();
        }

    };

    private void updateDisplay() {
        datainicial.setText(new StringBuilder()
                // Month is 0 based so add 1
                .append(dia).append("/").append(mes + 1).append("/")
                .append(ano).append(" "));

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Use o método `setMinDate`. Veja um exemplo, se quiser definir a data mínima a partir do momento atual, basta fazer desta forma abaixo:

```
datePicker.setMinDate(System.currentTimeMillis() - 1000);
```

Caso queira limitar a data mínima por uma data específica, você pode usar o Calendar, por exemplo:

```
final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();  
calendar.set(2010, Calendar.OCTOBER, Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
datePicker.setMinDate(calendar.getTimeInMillis());
```

Comment: Porquê `- 1000`?

Comment: Devido a implementação base da classe Datepicker, não é possível definir a data minima como exactamente agora.
Ref.: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13661788/how-to-set-minimum-datepicker-date-to-current-date

De qualquer forma, estamos a falar de retirar um segundo!

Comment: Amigo adicionei o datePicker.setMinDate(System.currentTimeMillis() - 1000). So que tem um problema: quando abre o emulador e eu cliclo na caixa de texto inicia com uma data antiga do ano de 1900... so depois que clico em uma data aleatoria. e clico novamente na caixa de texto é que aparece do mes e ano corrente.

Comment: como faço agora para ter duas datas(uma inicial e outra final) no meu app?

Answer (score 0):

Olá, acredito que não precisa mais, né? rs... De toda maneira, assim como eu, outros podem se deparar com algo parecido.

Bom, eu passei por um problema similar, onde eu precisava deixar habilitado apenas um range de data específico: 45 dias atrás até o dia anterior.

Eu fiz assim:

```
val dateValidatorMin: DateValidator =
    DateValidatorPointForward.from(
        Calendar.getInstance().timeInMillis - 45.days.toLong(DurationUnit.MILLISECONDS))

val dateValidatorMax: DateValidator =
    DateValidatorPointBackward.before(
        Calendar.getInstance().timeInMillis - 1.days.toLong(DurationUnit.MILLISECONDS))

val dateValidator: DateValidator = CompositeDateValidator.allOf(listOf(dateValidatorMin, dateValidatorMax))

val constraints: CalendarConstraints =
    CalendarConstraints.Builder()
        .setValidator(dateValidator)
        .build()

val builder = MaterialDatePicker.Builder.dateRangePicker()
    .setCalendarConstraints(constraints)
    .setTitleText(getString(R.string.label_select_date_range))

val picker = builder.build()
```

Dessa forma, hoje (18/01/23), o calendário mostra habilitado apenas o intervalo entre 05/12/22 e 17/01/23.

Espero que possa ajudar alguém.

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).